# Is there a way to check if a user is connected to a site through Tor using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, connection, tor

I would like to be able to display a message or etc if the user is connected through Tor. This will not need to be completely secure, and it should be client side. It can use an external API or site to get the IP address or something similar if necessary.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12395/how-does-check-torproject-org-know-if-youre-using-tor/12396#12396

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38498/detecting-tor-proxy-by-reading-request-headers/38503#38503

Comment: You just need to check their IP against a list of known exit addresses.  I can't think of any way to make this 100% client side (you'll need to know their IP and be able to check it against a list.  If you are able to use server side scripting to create a dynamic JS file that checks their IP against a pre-determined, frequently updated list of addresses I suppose you can make it work.  On my site here I publish a list of addresses (updated every 10 mins) you're free to use. https://drew-phillips.com/tor-exit-list.txt

Answer (score 3):

I check Tor with some probability by using this features:

- performance.now()  (always rounded to 100.0 in Tor)  (Date.now() is rounded too)
- navigator.hardwareConcurrency  (always 1 in Tor)
- devicePixelRatio  (always 1 in Tor)

Example:

```
var isTor = true;

if (navigator.hardwareConcurrency && navigator.hardwareConcurrency !== 1) {
    //This may not happen in Tor Browser because in Tor hardwareConcurrency is always 1
    isTor ＝ false;
}

if (window.devicePixelRatio && devicePixelRatio !== 1) {
    //This may not happen in Tor Browser because in Tor devicePixelRatio is always 1
    isTor ＝ false;
}

checkTor_byCurTime()
//Do something...

checkTor_byCurTime();
//Do something again...

checkTor_byCurTime();
// <<< Here you can use isTor var >>>

function checkTor_byCurTime() {
    if (performance.now() % 100 !== 0) {
        //This may not happen in Tor Browser but in other browsers it happens almost every time
        isTor = false;
    }
}
```

If you don't need sync check you can also add setTimeout calls:

```
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 1);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 2);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 3);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 5);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 7);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 11);
setTimeout(checkTor_byCurTime, 13);
```

Here is polyfills for used functions:

```
if (!window.performance) window.performance = {};
if (!performance.now) performance.now = function() { return Date.now(); };
if (!Date.now()) Date.now = function() { return (new Date).getTime(); };
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://openinternet.io/tor/istor.js) is a JavaScript file you can load to see if the visitor is using Tor.  It will set `window._isTor` to `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the remote IP that loaded the script is coming from a Tor exit node.

Load it on your pages like this (domain supports TLS 1.0 - TLS 1.2 connections, no SSL):

```
<script src="//openinternet.io/tor/istor.js"></script>
```

Check with:

```
<script>
    if (typeof window._isTor != 'undefined' && window._isTor == true) {
        // VISITOR IS USING TOR - code here
    } else {
        // not using Tor or the value was undefined
    }
</script>
```

Either put it in the `<head>` tags (will slow down page load time) or defer loading it and check the value once it finished.

I'll provide the source code (PHP) of the script that dynamically generates that JavaScript if you'd like.

I also plan on keeping that URL active for as long as possible - but make no guarantees of availability, reliability, or that it will stay up for years.

EDIT:  It should be noted, that for a while now Tor enables NoScript by default which will likely block JS loaded from another domain, so this may or may not work.